# How to expose mysql table schema as JPA object using Odata4j without maven

Tags: mysql, jpa, odata4j

I have to generate JPA objects for mysql tables using odata4J , as i am new to web services i have followed some online resources created following tasks;

1. Created new database connection under "Database Development"
2. Added eclipse link and mysql connector libraries through windows-> preferences->user library
3. Changed project Facets to JPA and configured further JPA configurations
4. Persistence.xml is generated and Populated Transaction Type from "Resource Local" under connection tab in the Persistence.xml
5. Generated JPA Entities from table by Right clicking on Project and selecting JPA Tools -> Generate entities from Table option.
6. One Java file is generated with the name of Table name.
7. I have written one Java class called TestProducer

public class TestProducer implements ODataProducerFactory {

```
String persistence = "testJPA";
String namespace = "testui5";
int maxResults = 50;

@Override 
public ODataProducer create(Properties properties) {

    String endpointUri = "http://localhost:8080/TestProducer.svc/";
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistence);
    JPAProducer producer = new JPAProducer(emf, namespace, maxResults);

    DefaultODataProducerProvider.setInstance(producer);
    return producer;
}
```

}

1. Am able to get result on console by calling create method in TestProducer from Main
2. But can any one tell me step by step procedure to access JPA Object through http , am not getting any online resouces.Please help me ..thanks in advance.